# O que são e quando usar Uniões Anônimas?

Tags: c, c++, tipagem, union

Durante a leitura de livro de estrutura de dados, foi apresentado brevemente o conceito de uniões anônimas, que seriam a definição de uma união sem especificar uma etiqueta (nome). Porém não entendi qual a utilidade desse tipo de dado.

Essa definição está correta?

Quando devo usar esse tipo de dado?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Imagino que saiba o que é uma união normal. Pois bem, a anônima não tem um nome, então a única forma de acessar é pelos seus membros.

Isso é útil quando vai declarar um união que só vai usar ali e mais nenhum outro lugar então não precisa criar um tipo ou um contrato de como deve ser o tipo de forma antecipada, só declara que será uma união com aquelas características e boa.

É mais válido quando é usado dentro de uma `struct`, assim em vez de acessar um membro da `struct` que é uma `union` e nesse membro acessar o membro da união, já acessa o membro da união diretamente como se ele fizesse parte da `struct`, mas como é uma `union` o espaço ocupado será apenas de um dos membros (o maior). Se esses membros estivessem declarados direto na `struct` não faria parte de uma `union`.

A utilidade não é grande, mas é útil em alguns casos. As duas formas:

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    union {
        char c;
        int i;
    };
} Tipo;
  
int main() {
    union {
        char c;
        int i;
    } x;
    x.i = 65;
    Tipo y;
    y.i = 65;
    printf("%c, %c", x.c, y.c);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/lGb2xU). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/qvaszmtp-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Struct/AnonymousUnion.c).

Answer (score 1):

Só para mostrar um exemplo que acho útil, imagina que você tem uma estrutura (vector) que representa coordenadas em 3 tres dimensoes (x, y, z). Mas você também precisa de uma estrutura que represente as cores, e que também possui três variáveis (red, green, blue). A estrutura das cores e do vector são muito parecidas o que muda é só o nome das variaveis membros. Além disso, voce já tem uma vasta gama de funções de manipulãcao de vetores, e que seria muito util se voce também as tivesse para a estrutura das cores. Para resolver o seu problema você poderia fazer o seguinte:

```
struct vec3{
    union{
        struct{
            float x, y, z;
        };

        struct{
            float r, g, b;
        };
    };
};

using color = vec3;
```

E se você tiver por exemplo uma função que normaliza um vetor você também podeira a usar para normalizar as cores, sem ter que redefinir a função.

Mas é claro que você também poderia definir a estrutura `vec3` só com as variaveis x, y e z, e usálas para as duas tarefas. Mas eu acho que assim o código fica bem mais natural.