# Retornando vários tipos de variável com auto no C++14

Tags: c++, tipagem, return, c++14

Eu criei uma classe, que tem 4 atributos `int valInt`, `float valFloat`, `double valDouble`, `bool valBool`, e um metódo chamado `getValue()` do tipo auto que retorna o valor de acordo com um outro atributo chamado type, segue o código:

```
auto
ShareMemory::
getValue()
{
    switch (type) {
        case 0:
            return valInt;
        break;

        case 1:
            return valFloat;
        break;

        case 2:
            return valDouble;
        break;

        case 3:
            return valBool;
        break;

    }
}
```

Ao compilar, ele acusa o seguinte erro na linha do `return valFloat`:

> error: 'auto' in return type deduced as 'float' here but deduced as 'int' in earlier return statement.*

Existe alguma outra forma de eu retornar qualquer um destes valores, sem ele puxar o tipo do primeiro return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse parece um caso clássico para usar [`variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) que permite que valores de tipos diferentes possam ser armazenados em um objeto *container* e que você vai desencapsular depois e usar como quiser. Isso tem sua utilidade, mas quase sempre indica que há um *design* ruim se você tem controle sobre a API, então veja se não pode fazer funções que retornem o valor específico, quase sempre pode. Se não puder você deixa para o código consumidor lidar com isso, não costuma ser legal.

O `variant` foi criado para ser uma opção mais segura da `union` que já existia desde o C. Como o `variant` foi introduzido só no C++17 eu sugiro mudar para esta versão ou mais nova. Mas se não puder, o `union` será sua solução. Só que aí fica pior porque você terá que se virar para identificar o tipo correto que retornou e usar do jeito que precisa. Por isso o retorno teria que ser algo composto, pode ser por exemplo uma `struct` que tenha um campo que seja uma *tag* do tipo (pode ser um valor numérico qualquer, uma enumeração por exemplo), e a união em si com o valor. Explico isso em [Como montar uma lista de objetos genéricos em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/180783/101). Também dá para retornar um [`pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair).

O `auto` não faz o que imagina. Não significa que aceita qualquer tipo, só indica que o compilador descobre sozinho que tipo vai retornar, e no caso ele não conseguiu descobrir porque nem manualmente isso é possível, é ambíguo.

Em algumas situações o [`any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) pode ser interessante, mas é mais raro ainda. E tem outras soluções possíveis, mas não devem ser melhores.

Fora isso poderá criar seu próprio `variant`, quem sabe até copiar do que já existe no C++17. Mas só faça isso se não puder mesmo usar uma versão mais nova. C++20 está aí pra ajudar a todos.

Pode ajudar:

- [Qual a diferenca entre os tipos de dados enum, struct e union em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/137393/101)
- [O que são e quando usar Uniões Anônimas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/355640/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre atributo e campo, nas classes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, abriu um leque de opções, e muita coisa que eu não conhecia, vou estuda-las, obrigado.